# Read user inputted .fasta file and parse using Biopython?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I am trying to create a python script where the user can type in their FASTA file and that file will then be parsed using Biopython. I am struggling to get this to work. The script I have thus far is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

file_name = input("Insert full file name including the fasta extension: ")
with open(file_name, "r") as inf:
  seq = inf.read()

from Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO import SimpleFastaParser
count = 0
total_len = 0
with open(inf) as in_file:
  for title, seq in SimpleFastaParser(in_file):
    count += 1
    total_len += len(seq)
print("%i records with total sequence length %i" % (count, total_len))
```

I would like the user to be prompted to type in their file and its extension and that file should be used to parse with Biopython such that that output is printed. I also want to be about to send the print output to a log file. Any help would be appreciate.

The purpose of the script is to take a fasta file, parse and trim primers. I know there is an easy method to do this using Biopython entirely but as per instruction Biopython can only be used to parse not trim. Any insight into this would be appreciated as well.

Comment: What is your current problem? Does the above code work to calculate and print the number of sequences and their cumulative length? What do you mean by "parsing"? I think I can help you out, but you have to tell me what's next.

Comment: @kamses Parsing just reads through the file. The parsing works but I can't get it to work unless I type in the file into the code. I want the user to be able to type in the file they want to use and then the script will use that file to parse with Biopython

Comment: Looks to me like it's your second `with` line. You're trying to open the `inf` variable which is automatically cleaned-up after the end of your first `with` statement. Try this: `with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file: #etc` It doesn't look like you need that first `with` statement at all

Comment: I tried what you said and I get the following error: `Insert full file name including the fasta extension: paired.fasta
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    file_name = input("Insert full file name including the fasta extension: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'paired' is not defined` where paired.fasta is the file name i am using.

Comment: `input()` should return a string (the user entry) which is just the type of argument you need to pass to `open()` to open the file. The error you pasted implies that python is trying to interpret your entry as python code, which is odd. Why don't you try using a command line argument instead, getting rid of input() for now? So... `import sys` and then `file_name = sys.argv[1]` at the top. Now run your script from the command line, `python test1.py paired.fasta`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. `input()` should work too, not sure what's going on there... but command line arguments are better in a lot of ways, one of which is giving you the benefit of tab-completion when searching file paths

Comment: If input() is giving `File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'paired' is not defined ` you might be using Python 2.7 and you should be using raw_input(). 2.7 Python interprets input from input() as code and raw_input as string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have two places where you open the fasta file

One where you store the contents in `seq`

Then you try to open `inf`, but you don't assign `inf` as a variable in this code snippet.
You may want to include some check to makes sure a valid file path was used
Also, this is a good case for using `argparse`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
from Bio.SeqIO
import os
import sys

def main(infile):
    # check that the file exists
    if not os.path.is_file(infile):
        print("file not found")
        sys.exit()
    count = 0
    total_len = 0
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(open(infile), "fasta"):
        count += 1
        total_len += len(seq_record.seq)

    print("%i records with total sequence length %i" % (count, total_len))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='some script to do something with fasta files',
                                     formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('-in', '--infile', type=str, default=None, required=True,
                        help='The path and file name of the fasta file')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    infile = args.infile

    main(infile)
```

If you need to use `input`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from Bio.SeqIO
import os
import sys

infile = input("Insert full file name including the fasta extension: ")
# remove any white space
infile = infile.strip()

# check that the file exists
if not os.path.is_file(infile):
    print("file not found")
    sys.exit()

count = 0
total_len = 0
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(open(infile), "fasta"):
    count += 1
    total_len += len(seq_record.seq)

print("%i records with total sequence length %i" % (count, total_len))
```